# Unified frontend side and backend side forms validation

Tags: html, spring, validation, backbone.js

I'm working on some framework (library) for declarative HTML forms definition (let name this definition as metamodel). The metamodel is saved as some JSON where user who defined the new form could specify whether the field is required, need specific regex for validation, depends from other field, how it looks on the search view and a lot of typical business stuff.

Based on that metamodel the HTML form is generated (the metamodel is forwarded between frontend and backend as JSON and the form values are also sent as JSON by REST services) and we have to introduce the fields validation.

Of course the validation needs to be introduced also on frontend and backend side. I would prefer to unified the validation from both sides by single mechanism.

Does somebody have any ideas how I could unified the frontend and backend validation in order to avoid duplication? Does it make any sense or should I reject my idea of unification and implement separate HTML and server side validation.

Any ideas and hint are welcome :)

PS. On the backend side I'm using Spring, on the frontend side I'm using backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Backend and front end validation are usually separate. For front end validation you might consider using backbone-validation library. 
https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation